# Migration upvote bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, migration

This question was originally posted on stackoverflow which I upvoted and answered (Question upvotes stood at 2).  It was then migrated to Database Administrators and had the original 2 upvotes.

I then noticed after migration that the arrow was not highlighted (Indicating that I have already voted the question) and was able to up vote the question again.  Unless my up vote for that question was lost/not correctly recorded this appears to be a bug when a question is migrated.

Below is the link to the actual question:

[Should I use a composite or single-column index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42585/which-non-clustered-index-should-i-have-to-use-composite-or-single-column-in-sql/42586#42586)